# Why is the "source to destination mapping" controls is missing?

Tags: interface, constraints

I am following an online tutorial on constraints transformation. The following is what I see in the tutorial
[image]m

This is what I see on my laptop

[image]

The interface is different and I couldn't continue with the tutorial.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

The UI for the constraint has changed, but the features are still there. Each axis has an alterable “source” option, which is equivalent to “mapping.”